# Changing tank drive (differential) mode to single joystick drive mode

Tags: motor, differential-drive

I bought 2 brushed motor controllers from China to use within my hobby-weight battle robot (http://www.banggood.com/ESC-Brushed-Speed-Controller-For-RC-Car-Truck-Boat-320A-7_2V-16V-p-915276.html).

These are intended for use with my 2 cordless drill motors which will be driving 
the left and right wheel respectively. The robot will therefore be steered in 
"tank mode" by varying the speed and direction of rotation of the 2 motors using 
the two joysticks on my Turnigy 9x transmitter.

I am seeking to refine the model and make it easier to operate so does anyone know of a way in which I can somehow synchronize the motors to get a single joystick steering system?  My transmitter has 9 available channels so if this is part of a solution then I am fine with it. I also have an Arduino available if needs be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to have something on the robot that can intercept your "single joystick" signal from the remote control and translate it to left/right wheel speeds.  Your arduino might be able to serve this purpose, with the appropriate shield.

For that calculation, check out [this question on calculating left and right motor speeds based on desired throttle and direction](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/2011/350).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what transmitter you use, but I would try to find settings for channel mixing on it.

You should mix +throttle input to +left and +right output and + turn to -right and +left.